# How to store data from html form to postgres database?

Tags: django

I have an HTML form of which data needs to be stored in the Database. My project structure is as:

```
 Form
 - _init_.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
 myapp
  migrations
  templates\mapp\form.html
  - _init_.py
  - admin.py
  - apps.py
  - models.py
  - tests.py
  - views.py
 - db.sqlite3
 - manage.py
```

How can I save my HTML form data to the Postgres database?

Form.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Form layout</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="register">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="body_grid">
                <span>Country </span>
                <select id="country"  class="frm-field required">
                    <option value="null">Select</option>
                    <option value="null">Headoffice</option>   
                    <option value="null">Residence</option>   
                    <option value="null">Office</option>                        
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow some steps.

1. Create a model for the data to be stored.
2. Create a form object and validate it in view.py to save th data.
3. In your setting.py installing PostgreSQL package. You can view this tutorial to install it https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/optional_postgresql_installation/